# Using Coda to access server SSH/sFTP

Tags: linux, ssh, vps, coda, panic

I have a VPS server and I lock down to only expose 3 ports 80, 443 and 22222 for ssh. So far I can connect to the server using Terminal (Mac) and Panic Transmit, but when I try to connect using Panic Coda the connection fail. What I am doing wrong?

I see Coda support sFTP and I can connect on Coda to the SSH, but not to the sFTP.

Ideas? Work around?

Thank you

Comment: Wow not a single comment! This should be a big issue

Comment: It's hard to know what configuration you've used in coda, or look for bugs without version numbers. I'm glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to what coda is actually doing, I can't say for sure.

Workaround could be to create an ssh tunnel and just use FTP, configure your FTP server or firewall to only allow loopback connections

Establish tunnel using something like:

```
ssh -o'Port 22222' -f user@server -L 3000:127.0.0.1:21 -N
```

Then point FTP at localhost, port 3000.

[HOWTO: SSH Tunneling Made Easy](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html)

Comment: You should probably contact Panic's support too, so they can either identify if you're doing something wrong or fix the issue in their application.

Comment: Please do contact Panic. Coda is wonderful and if it's their problem they will get it fixed.